# powershell script to to check disk space for each server individually

Tags: powershell, vbscript, diskspace

I have a script which I got from somewhere from MS forum
this script works absolutely fine.I get the email and html file as needed
But since in a multi domain environment I need to provide different credentials
to different servers.So instead of a for loop for each server in the list using same 
credentials,it should treat each server with its credentials but in the same file and email
Any Idea how to get this...
Thanks in advance

```
$freeSpaceFileName = "c:\script\FreeSpace.htm"
$serverlist = "c:\script\computers.txt"
#$SecurePassword = 'Atlantic12' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
#$Credential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential 'tnt\administrator', $SecurePassword

$CredentialList = @{
    Cred1 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList 'xax\administrator', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Atlantic' -AsPlainText -Force);
    Cred2 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList 'laptop\admin', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force);
    }

    $warning = 50
$critical = 30
New-Item -ItemType file $freeSpaceFileName -Force
# Getting the free space info using WMI
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk  | Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} | format-table DeviceID, VolumeName,status,Size,FreeSpace | Out-File FreeSpace.txt
# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeHtmlHeader
{
param($fileName)
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"
Add-Content $fileName '<meta http-equiv="refresh" CONTENT="5">'
Add-Content $fileName '<title>All Servers DiskSpace Report&copy;</title>'
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
add-content $fileName  "<!--"
add-content $fileName  "td {"
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 20px;"
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "body {"
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
add-content $fileName  ""
add-content $fileName  "table {"
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
add-content $fileName  "}"
add-content $fileName  "-->"
add-content $fileName  "</style>"
Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
Add-Content $fileName "<body>"
add-content $fileName  "<br></br>"
add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%' align=center>"
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>"
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='5'><strong>All Servers DiskSpace Report &copy; - $date</strong></font>"
add-content $fileName  "</td>"
add-content $fileName  "</tr>"
add-content $fileName  "</table>"
add-content $fileName  "<br></br>"
}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Drive</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>"
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

Function writeHtmlFooter
{
param($fileName)

Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function writeDiskInfo
{
param($fileName,$devId,$volName,$frSpace,$totSpace)
$totSpace=[math]::Round(($totSpace/1073741824),2)
$frSpace=[Math]::Round(($frSpace/1073741824),2)
$usedSpace = $totSpace - $frspace
$usedSpace=[Math]::Round($usedSpace,2)
$freePercent = ($frspace/$totSpace)*100
$freePercent = [Math]::Round($freePercent,0)
 if ($freePercent -gt $warning)
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"

 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$freePercent</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
 elseif ($freePercent -le $critical)
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 #<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
 else
 {
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FBB917' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 # #FBB917
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
 }
}
Function sendEmail
{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName)
$from=New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "server.space@tnt.com"
$to= New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "ttamboli2@tnt.com"
$cc= New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress "ttamboli2@tnt.com"
$subject="Servers Disk space report - $Date" 
$smtphost="192.168.1.42"
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to,$subject, $body
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true
$smtp.Send($msg)

}

writeHtmlHeader $freeSpaceFileName
foreach($server in Get-Content $serverlist)
{
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server</strong></font></td>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>"
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<br>"
 writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName

 $ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path c:\Computers.csv;
 foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) 
 {
 Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Credential $CredentialList[$Computer.Credential] |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3}
{
 Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
 writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
    }
 }
 writeHtmlFooter $freeSpaceFileName
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')
#sendEmail arif@tnt.com ttamboli2@tnt.com "Disk Space Report - $Date" hub1 $freeSpaceFileName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code you have provided has a lot of HTML formatting in it, I will share with you a much more simplified example of how to achieve what you're after.

1. Turn your `computers.txt` into a CSV file, with two columns, that references a credential object by some friendly name (eg. `cred1` or `cred2`)
2. In PowerShell create a `HashTable` of different credentials, and use the same friendly name that you used in the CSV file
3. For each computer in the CSV file, use its name and credential to connect to WMI

### Computers.csv

```
Name,Credential
dc01,cred1
dc02,cred1
dc03,cred1
exch01,cred2
exch02,cred2
exch03,cred2
client01,cred3
client02,cred3
client03,cred3
```

### PowerShell Script

```
# Build a list of key/value pairs, to uniquely reference each of several credentials
$CredentialList = @{
    Cred1 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList 'domain\user123', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password123' -AsPlainText -Force);
    Cred2 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList 'domain\user456', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password456' -AsPlainText -Force);
    Cred3 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList 'domain\user789', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password789' -AsPlainText -Force);
    }

# Get a list of computer/credential pairs
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\Computers.csv;

# For each computer in the CSV file, use the appropriate credential to contact WMI
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Credential $CredentialList[$Computer.Credential];
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the amazing fix....Trevor
But I'm getting a cannot index into a null array error at line     Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Credential $CredentialList[$Computer.Credential];

Comment: I've updated my question with the script that I have modified as per your suggestion.

Comment: Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\nn.ps1:161 char:98
+  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Credential $CredentialList[ <<<< $Computer.Cred
ential] |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray